# Prompted for input twice in query

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Hoping someone can shed some light on a problem I'm having with vb and Access. The general issue is this:

- There is a form that supplies user input to a query
- The query runs with the user input from the form
- A report is generated that relies on a vb module to generate percentiles from the query.

Basically the form provides input to a query, which in turn provides input to a module within a report.

The issue I am having is that the user enters input once on the form and then is prompted (with pop-up windows) to enter the data again. Only the data from the second go-around is reflected on the report. Is there a way to have the form data remain and the query not be prompted for it again?

Below is my code from the module (in the report). As you'll see I attempt to pass the parameters from the form but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
Public Function PercentileRst(RstName As String, fldName As String, PercentileValue As
Double) As Double
'This function will calculate the percentile of a recordset.

Dim PercentileTemp As Double
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim RstOrig As DAO.Recordset
Dim RstSorted As DAO.Recordset


Dim xVal As Double
Dim iRec As Long
Dim i As Long

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("qryMaster")
'i need to pass the parameters to the query
qdf.Parameters!minA = Forms!demo_form.min_assets
qdf.Parameters!maxA = Forms!demo_form.max_assets
qdf.Parameters!minP = Forms!demo_form.min_parts
qdf.Parameters!maxP = Forms!demo_form.max_parts


Set RstOrig = qdf.OpenRecordset()

RstOrig.Sort = fldName
Set RstSorted = RstOrig.OpenRecordset()
RstSorted.MoveLast
RstSorted.MoveFirst
xVal = ((RstSorted.RecordCount - 1) * PercentileValue) + 1
'x now contains the record number we are looking for.
'Note x may not be     whole number
iRec = Int(xVal)
xVal = xVal - iRec
'i now contains first record to look at and
'x contains diff to next record
RstSorted.Move iRec - 1
PercentileTemp = RstSorted(fldName)
If xVal > 0 Then
RstSorted.MoveNext
PercentileTemp = ((RstSorted(fldName) - PercentileTemp) * xVal) + PercentileTemp
End If
RstSorted.Close
RstOrig.Close
Set RstSorted = Nothing
Set RstOrig = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing
PercentileRst = PercentileTemp
End Function
```

The form I am using passes 4 parameters to the query. Within the query I use the following criteria: 'Between [minA] And [maxA]' and 'Between [minP] And [maxP]'

Is there some way in the query's SQL to initialize the values of these parameters to the values in the form?

The form is opens the query and the report when the user clicks 'OK'.

Comment: qryMaster is used as the report's record source.  Based on the user input (from demo_form) qryMaster runs and (in theory) the percentile function operates on qryMaster and generates output to the summary report.

Answer (score 1):

*qryMaster* includes parameters and is the report's record source.  Therefore when the report first opens, Access asks the user to supply values for those parameters.

Later, you use *qryMaster* again in a procedure which loads its result set into a `DAO.Recordset`.  At that time your code supplies values for the parameters, so the user is not asked to supply values a second time.  However, that doesn't have any effect on the situation at form open.

Try a revised *qryMaster* where you point to the form's controls:

```sql
WHERE
        some_field BETWEEN Forms!demo_form!min_assets
            AND Forms!demo_form!max_assets
    AND another_field BETWEEN Forms!demo_form!min_parts
            AND Forms!demo_form!max_parts
```

The db engine can look at those controls on *demo_form* to get the values it needs, so won't ask the user to supply parameter values separately.

Comment: i will give that a try. once i change the query to directly reference the form, how should I change my module within the report? basically how (if at all) do I pass the parameters when I reference the query in my vb code? (thanks again)